# open viewcontroller embedded in navigation view in swift UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to open my view controller (with storyboard) which is embedded in a navigation view from the scende delegate

i am doing something like this

```
let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
        let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
```

however i can't see the navigation bar, i mean, i just see the viewcontroller content
i need to open the navigation view as well

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is `HomeViewController` the name of your `UINavigationViewController` ?

If not, then this is expected.

Give your `UINavigationViewController` an identifier in the storyboard like you did for `HomeViewController` and then replace:

```
let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourNavControllerIdenfier") as! UINavigationController
self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
```

Try this and see if it gives you the result you want

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to make your NavigationController as the root vc, not the HomeViewController;

Secondly, the default Navigation bar style is transparent, if you want to see it, you can customise it, for example:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```